# Left Shift+Ctrl+Backspace stopped working in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, ubuntu-16.04, hotkeys

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> is a hot hotkey to navigate to "Last Edit Location".

Suddenly it stopped working on the left side, meanwhile  the right side combination of the same keys work as expected.

Actually, I realized that left combination of <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> does not work at all. So  <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> does not show  the popup "Choose content to paste".

Further  more  I realized it's a system wide problem, in Google Chrome browser <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> supposed to reopen closed tub, Instead triggered just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> which opens a net tub. I have Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: 1) Restart computer (just to be sure that it's not some sort of glitch) -- even if you have Mac/Linux there 2) `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` -- there is a button next to the search field -- it allows to search by shortcuts -- see if it will recognize it at all. If not -- maybe some OS-level functionality (global hotkey) have registered it for own needs.

Comment: I did all the steps you suggested. Actually search by hotkey recognizes only Ctrl+Backspace or Shift+Backspace but not both. The right ones are ok.

Comment: What OS you have there? I mean -- does it have some sort of program that will show virtual keyboard or alike (e.g. show current keyboard layout where when you press every key it will highlight it)? If you do -- see if you can press that key combination there. Other than that (global hotkey for some app or OS functionality) -- no ideas.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: No ideas on actual reason from my end, sorry. I may only suggest to set another shortcut for that action ... or ask Support:https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! I tried console utility "showkey" all  keys are ok. So it's an IDE's problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that it's an old well known issue with ubuntu. 
First I figured out that the problem rises when you use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to switch keyboard layouts. The issue is described here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1245473

Then It's downed on me that the real issue is that keyboard layout switching triggers on key press instead of key release. So this prevents any additional key strokes to be used with aforementioned combination https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/36812.

Here is the solution:
 https://habrahabr.ru/post/87408/
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1683383

In a few words, you need to apply a patch to the Xorg source and build xorg-server from patched files. For some reasons I failed to implement this solution and broke my xorg-server. However, when I reinstalled Ubuntu the problem has gone.